# Is it possible to configure Nginx-Ingress and Nginx Web Server on same host machine?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube, nginx-ingress

I have an existing install of Nginx Web Server on an Ubuntu VM (Digital Ocean). On the same VM I have managed to install Jenkins.

The Jenkins instance is accessible via an https domain and I have completed the following steps with respect to this:

1. Registered domain for the instance on Namecheap
2. Pointed the domain to DigitalOcean Name Servers
3. Configured a server block in Nginx Web Server for the instance
4. Configure LetsEncrypt certificate for the domain, on the VM and also on Nginx Web Server

The Jenkins instance is up and accessible as expected on the https domain.

My issue now is that I cannot access a site/service that I have configured via Nginx-Ingress and minikube.

I have installed minikube on the same VM and enabled Nginx-Ingress via :

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

The service/site I am trying to access is the Hello-World app given [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) .

I have verified that the Ingress controller is directing traffic as expected using :

```
curl hello-world.info
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-93421-bc890-92vj5
```

The Nginx-Ingress components are also running normally.

In /etc/hosts I have added entries for both the Jenkins domain and the Hello-World domain. The Jenkins domain, though, works by default without any additional config to /etc/hosts.

```
192.167.77.7  jenkinserver.dev  hello-world.info
```

My question  : Can minikube Nginx-Ingress work side by side in this way alongside Nginx Web Server installed on the host ?

My use-case is to eventually run some service on minikube and this service should be accessible via https domain , just as I can currently access Jenkins. The corresponding config for LetsEncrypt certificates, domain and Ingress rules will as expected be entirely in K8S context.

***NB : I do not to wanr to configure the service/site as an additional server block in the Nginx Web Server context. The service/site has to run strictly in minikube/Kubernetes context.***

Comment: Technically you can, only I think it's a very strange use-case.

Usually there is a tendency to separate the NON-Kubernetes workflow from the nodes of the cluster.

Comment: Can you check whether ingress is configured to listen to the correct host name or not and Can you cross check ingress rules also

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu I think the check is already in my question. Unless I am doing it wrongly maybe . How do I check for that ?